# Variable JS and PHP,

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I need to multiply a variable obtained from:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://indicador.eof.cl/js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> indicadorEOF (8) </ script>
```

<------------ this Variable

Then my php code is:

```
$ dollar = '<script type="text/javascript"> indicadorEOF (8) </ script>';
$ result = $dollar*$variablefrommysql;
```

My result should be 100 but I get 0, I mean I read js variable as an integer, and probe with

```
$ dollar = (int) $ dollar;
```

But not because it does not take ... I can not perform the operation.

Comment: What do these statements do - `$ dollar = '<script type="text/javascript"> indicadorEOF (8) </ script>';
$ result = $ dollar $ variablefrommysql;`? There is also a space between `$` and a variable. Is this your real code?

Comment: Sorry is $result = $dollar*$variablefrommysql;

Answer (score 1):

Not really clear why or what you are doing here. $dollar should be a string as that is what you have set it to.

I assume that you really want something to come back from the JavaScript?

However, the JS executes in the browser and PHP on the server. So to have a "conversation" between the two, you need to get JS to talk back to the server.

Rather easier would be to get JS to put the value into a hidden form and push that back to the server for processing. Even so, this takes a full round trip to process. From the server to the browser and back to the server again.